# post Jquery input values from calculator and pass into link parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a jQuery calculator that I built using a conversion tool called Appizy. It takes a excel calculation and converts it into jQuery and html.

Here is the site: https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/pricing-calc/

What I am trying to do is grab the input values that are displayed and append them to a link for example i want to create a dynamic link with these parameters

```
 ?demo_request_type=es&active_clients=[NUMBER]&active_caregivers=[NUMBER]
```

where number is, the input values from the calculator (NOT RESULTS) should show.

Would much appreciate any suggestion in the right direction.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to solve this by adding a value to my inputs

```
<input type="text" id="qta_field1" value="${item.value}"/>
```

I think added this my button link

```
onclick="this.href='http://www.google.com?demo_request_type=example&active_clients='+document.getElementById('qta_field1').value +'&active_caregivers='+document.getElementById('qta_field2').value"
```

this opens up a new window with the parameters set in the input field by the user